# Add labels to group similar variables in a gtsummary generated table

Tags: r, gtsummary

How do you add labels to group similar variables in a gtsummary generated table? For example, if survey respondents are able to select multiple races (captured in separate variables), I would like a heading for the race variables:

[image: Image adapted from tbl_summary output]

Here is the tbl_summary output:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(knitr)
tibble::tribble(
  ~race___1, ~race___2, ~race___3, ~race___4, ~race___5,
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
       "No",      "No",     "Yes",      "No",      "No",
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
       "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes"
  ) %>% tbl_summary() %>% as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 10** |
| --- | --- |
| race___1 |  |
| No | 10 (100%) |
| race___2 |  |
| No | 10 (100%) |
| race___3 | 1 (10%) |
| race___4 |  |
| No | 10 (100%) |
| race___5 | 9 (90%) |

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `bstfun::add_variable_grouping()` function (https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/bstfun/reference/add_variable_grouping.html).

Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

tbl <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~race___1, ~race___2, ~race___3, ~race___4, ~race___5,
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
    "No",      "No",     "Yes",      "No",      "No",
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes",
    "No",      "No",      "No",      "No",     "Yes"
  ) %>% 
  tbl_summary(value = everything() ~ "Yes") %>%
  bstfun::add_variable_grouping(
    "Race" = c("race___1", "race___2", "race___3", "race___4", "race___5")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>