# gtsummary: make variable group labels bold

Tags: gtsummary

I'm making a descriptive table for the cluster analysis work I'm doing. I'm using the `gtsummary` R package. There is an overall column, a cluster 1 column, a cluster 2 column, a cluster 3 column, and a p-value column. Each row is a variable. Here is the code I'm using, and everything works perfectly (thanks to [Add labels to group similar variables in a gtsummary generated table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439249/add-labels-to-group-similar-variables-in-a-gtsummary-generated-table)):

```
library(gtsummary)

table_rows <- c("Years_At_Diagnosis", 
  "Sex", 
  "Long_Bone", 
  "Central_Nervous_System",
  "Hypothalamic_or_Pituitary",
  "Facial_or_Orbits",
  "Heart",
  "Large_Vessels",
  "Lungs",
  "Perirenal_or_Periadrenal",
  "Skin",
  "Testis",
  "Lymph_Nodes",
  "Digestive_Tract",
  "Other_Organ_Involvement",
  "Hematologic_Malignancy",
  "Associated_LCH",
  "Associated_RDD",
  "BRAFV600E_Status",
  "MAP2K1_Status",
  "Other_Mutations",
  "Cardiovascular_Risk_Score",
  "N_of_organs",
  "cluster")

row_names <- c(Years_At_Diagnosis ~ "Age at diagnosis", 
               Sex ~ "Sex", 
               Long_Bone ~ "Long Bones", 
               Central_Nervous_System ~ "Central Nervous System",
               Hypothalamic_or_Pituitary ~ "Hypothalamic/Pituitary",
               Facial_or_Orbits ~ "Facial/Orbits",
               Heart ~ "Heart",
               Large_Vessels ~ "Large Vessels",
               Lungs ~ "Lungs",
               Perirenal_or_Periadrenal ~ "Perirenal/Periadrenal",
               Skin ~ "Skin",
               Testis ~ "Testis",
               Lymph_Nodes ~ "Lymph Nodes",
               Digestive_Tract ~ "Digestive Tract",
               Hematologic_Malignancy ~ "Hematologic Malignancy",
               Other_Organ_Involvement ~ "Other Organ Involvement",
               Associated_LCH ~ "Associated LCH",
               Associated_RDD ~ "Associated RDD",
               BRAFV600E_Status ~ "BRAF V600E Mutation",
               MAP2K1_Status ~ "MAP2K1 Mutation",
               Other_Mutations ~ "Other Mutations",
               Cardiovascular_Risk_Score ~ "Cardiovascular Risk Score",
               N_of_organs ~ "Number of Organs Involved") 

clusterTable <- tbl_summary(ECDpatients,
                            include = table_rows,
                            by="cluster", 
                            label = row_names,
                            statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sd}", all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"),
                            type = list(N_of_organs ~ "continuous"), # Was not recognized as continuous, for some reason
                            digits = list(Years_At_Diagnosis ~ c(2,2), Cardiovascular_Risk_Score ~ c(2,2), N_of_organs ~ c(2,2)),
                            missing = "no") |> 
  add_p() |> 
  add_overall() |> 
  modify_spanning_header(update = c("stat_1", "stat_2", "stat_3") ~ "**Cluster**") |>
  modify_header(update = label ~ "") |>
  bstfun::add_variable_grouping("Demographics" = c("Years_At_Diagnosis", "Sex"),
                                "Organ Pattern" = c("Long_Bone", 
                                                    "Central_Nervous_System",
                                                    "Hypothalamic_or_Pituitary",
                                                    "Facial_or_Orbits",
                                                    "Heart",
                                                    "Large_Vessels",
                                                    "Lungs",
                                                    "Perirenal_or_Periadrenal",
                                                    "Skin",
                                                    "Testis",
                                                    "Lymph_Nodes",
                                                    "Digestive_Tract",
                                                    "Other_Organ_Involvement"),
                                "Concomitant Disorders" = c("Hematologic_Malignancy",
                                                            "Associated_LCH",
                                                            "Associated_RDD"),
                                "Genetics" = c("BRAFV600E_Status",
                                               "MAP2K1_Status",
                                               "Other_Mutations"),
                                "Other Features" = c("Cardiovascular_Risk_Score",
                                                     "N_of_organs"))
```

[Descriptive Table of Clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcGyK.png)

How do I make the group labels, but not the variable labels, **bold**?

I've tried to solve this issue (i.e. making variable group labels **bold**) by looking into the `gtsummary` documentation and many tutorials, and the (poor) documentation of `bstfun::add_variable_grouping()`,  but I can't make it.